# Что-то не так со мной или с задачей?

Tags: java, алгоритм

> Вы решили запрограммировать летающего робота, который максимально
>   быстро сможет пройти трехмерный лабиринт. Вам повезло, и у Вас есть
>   план этого лабиринта. Внешне он выглядит как трёхмерный куб, состоящий
>   из n3n3 маленьких кубиков и ограниченный со всех сторон стенкой. Все
>   внутренние стены перпендикулярны сторонам куба, причем стоят они,
>   разделяя внутренние кубики. У каждого внутреннего кубика есть своя
>   целочисленная координата от 0 до n3−1n3−1, причём нумеруются они
>   подряд идущими слоями, то есть для кубика с гранью 3:
>
> ```
> первый слой:   второй слой:   третий слой:
> 00 01 02       09 10 11       18 19 20
> 03 04 05       12 13 14       21 22 23
> 06 07 08       15 16 17       24 25 26
> ```
>
> Для лабиринтов больших размеров, аналогично.
>
> На вход Вашей программе подается размер лабиринта n, координата входа
>   в лабиринт(некоторая координата внутреннего кубика, лежащего на одной
>   из граней), координата выхода из кубика (некоторая координата
>   внутреннего кубика, лежащего на одной из граней, не совпадающая с
>   координатами входа) и количество внутренних стен k, за которым следует
>   соответственное количество пар координат кубиков, между которыми стоит
>   стена. Ваша задача через пробел вывести наикратчайшую
>   последовательность координат, по которым пролетит робот от входа к
>   выходу. Если таких последовательностей несколько – выведите
>   наименьшую. Например, в первом тесте различных путей 6:
>
> 0 1 3 7 ; 0 1 5 7 ; 0 2 3 7 ; 0 2 6 7 ; 0 4 5 7 ; 0 4 6 7
>
> Они упорядочены по возрастанию, поэтому ответ к задаче -- 0 1 3 7.
>
> Если до выхода добраться нельзя, выведите «-1».

Я решил эту задачу но у меня не проходит 9 тест на степике

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int kol, entry, exit, k, xEn = 0, yEn = 0, xEx = 0, yEx = 0, zEn = 0, zEx = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        kol = scanner.nextInt();
        entry = scanner.nextInt();
        exit = scanner.nextInt();
        k = scanner.nextInt();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int[][][] massiv = new int[kol][kol][kol];
        int[] massiv2 = new int[kol * kol * kol];
        ArrayList<String> lis = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> questStr = new ArrayList<>();
        if (k != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
                int num2 = scanner.nextInt();
                String numer = num1 + " " + num2;
                list.add(numer);
            }
        }
        scanner.close();

        int i1 = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < kol; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < kol; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < kol; x++) {
                    massiv[x][y][z] = i1;
                    massiv2[i1] = -1;
                    if (i1 == entry) {
                        xEn = x;
                        yEn = y;
                        zEn = z;
                    }
                    if (i1 == exit) {
                        xEx = x;
                        yEx = y;
                        zEx = z;
                    }
                    i1++;
                }
            }
        }


        massiv2 = createMap(xEn, yEn, massiv2, massiv, kol, entry);
        /*for (int z = 0; z < kol; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < kol; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < kol; x++) {
                    System.out.print(massiv2[massiv[x][y][z]] + " ");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }*/
        lis = findPuth(massiv, kol, massiv2, entry, exit, zEn, zEx, exit, String.valueOf(""), lis, list);
        if (lis.size() > 0) {
            Long min = Long.valueOf(lis.get(0).replace(" ", ""));
            String minimum = lis.get(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < lis.size(); i++) {
                if (Long.valueOf(lis.get(i).replace(" ", "")) < min){
                    min = Long.valueOf(lis.get(i).replace(" ", ""));
                    minimum = lis.get(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(minimum);
        } else System.out.println(-1);

    }

    public static int[] createMap(int xEn, int yEn, int[] massiv2, int[][][] massiv, int kol, int entry) {
        massiv2[entry] = 0;
        int m1, m2, m3, m4, d, i = 0, x, y, z;
        String findNumber;
        String number;
        while (true) {
            number = Arrays.toString(massiv2);
            if (i == kol * kol * kol && number.contains(String.valueOf(-1))) i = 0;
            if (i == kol * kol * kol && !number.contains(String.valueOf(-1))) break;
            if (!number.contains(String.valueOf(-1))) break;
            if (massiv2[i] > 0 || (massiv2[i] == 0 && i == entry)) {
                findNumber = findNumberInMass(massiv, i, kol);
                x = Integer.parseInt(findNumber.split(" ")[0]);
                y = Integer.parseInt(findNumber.split(" ")[1]);
                z = Integer.parseInt(findNumber.split(" ")[2]);
                d = massiv2[i];

                if (x == xEn && y == yEn && z + 1 < kol && massiv2[massiv[x][y][z + 1]] == -1)
                    massiv2[massiv[x][y][z + 1]] = d + 1;
                if (x == xEn && y == yEn && z - 1 >= 0 && massiv2[massiv[x][y][z - 1]] == -1)
                    massiv2[massiv[x][y][z - 1]] = d + 1;

                if (x - 1 >= 0) {
                    m1 = massiv[x - 1][y][z];
                    if (massiv2[m1] == -1 && m1 != entry)
                        massiv2[m1] = d + 1;
                }
                if (x + 1 < kol) {
                    m3 = massiv[x + 1][y][z];
                    if (massiv2[m3] == -1 && m3 != entry)
                        massiv2[m3] = d + 1;
                }
                if (y - 1 >= 0) {
                    m2 = massiv[x][y - 1][z];
                    if (massiv2[m2] == -1 && m2 != entry)
                        massiv2[m2] = d + 1;
                }
                if (y + 1 < kol) {
                    m4 = massiv[x][y + 1][z];
                    if (massiv2[m4] == -1 && m4 != entry)
                        massiv2[m4] = d + 1;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return massiv2;
    }


    public static String findNumberInMass(int masiv2[][][], int needFind, int kol) {
        for (int z = 0; z < kol; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < kol; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < kol; x++) {
                    if (masiv2[x][y][z] == needFind) return x + " " + y + " " + z;
                }
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(0);
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> findPuth(int masiv[][][], int kol, int masiv2[],
                                             int entry, int exit, int zEn, int zEx, int i,
                                             String questStr, ArrayList<String> lis, ArrayList<String> list) {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
        int m1;
        int m2;
        int m3;
        int m4;
        int z1;
        int z2;
        questStr += i + " ";
        String findNumber = findNumberInMass(masiv, i, kol);
        x = Integer.parseInt(findNumber.split(" ")[0]);
        y = Integer.parseInt(findNumber.split(" ")[1]);
        z = Integer.parseInt(findNumber.split(" ")[2]);
        if (z - 1 >= 0 && zEn < zEx) {
            z2 = masiv[x][y][z - 1];
            if (masiv2[z2] + 1 == masiv2[i] && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(z2))
                    && (!list.contains(z2 + " " + i) && !list.contains(i + " " + z2)) && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(entry))) {
                findPuth(masiv, kol, masiv2, entry, exit, zEn, zEx, z2, questStr, lis, list);
            }
        }
        if (z + 1 < kol && zEn > zEx) {
            z1 = masiv[x][y][z + 1];
            if ( masiv2[z1] - 1 == masiv2[i] && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(z1))
                    && (!list.contains(z1 + " " + i) && !list.contains(i + " " + z1)) && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(entry))) {
                findPuth(masiv, kol, masiv2, entry, exit, zEn, zEx, z1, questStr, lis, list);
            }
        }
        if (y - 1 >= 0) {
            m4 = masiv[x][y - 1][z];
            if ((masiv2[m4] + 1 == masiv2[i] || masiv2[m4] - 1 == masiv2[i]) && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(m4))
                    && (!list.contains(m4 + " " + i) && !list.contains(i + " " + m4)) && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(entry))) {
                findPuth(masiv, kol, masiv2, entry, exit, zEn, zEx, m4, questStr, lis, list);
            }
        }
        if (x - 1 >= 0) {
            m3 = masiv[x - 1][y][z];
            if ((masiv2[m3] + 1 == masiv2[i] || masiv2[m3] - 1 == masiv2[i]) && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(m3))
                    && (!list.contains(m3 + " " + i) && !list.contains(i + " " + m3)) && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(entry))) {
                findPuth(masiv, kol, masiv2, entry, exit, zEn, zEx, m3, questStr, lis, list);

            }
        }
        if (y + 1 < kol) {
            m2 = masiv[x][y + 1][z];
            if ((masiv2[m2] + 1 == masiv2[i] || masiv2[m2] - 1 == masiv2[i]) && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(m2))
                    && (!list.contains(m2 + " " + i) && !list.contains(i + " " + m2)) && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(entry))) {
                findPuth(masiv, kol, masiv2, entry, exit, zEn, zEx, m2, questStr, lis, list);
            }
        }
        if (x + 1 < kol) {
            m1 = masiv[x + 1][y][z];
            if ((masiv2[m1] + 1 == masiv2[i] || masiv2[m1] - 1 == masiv2[i]) && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(m1))
                    && (!list.contains(m1 + " " + i) && !list.contains(i + " " + m1)) && !Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(entry))) {
                findPuth(masiv, kol, masiv2, entry, exit, zEn, zEx, m1, questStr, lis, list);
            }
        }

        if (Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" ")).contains(String.valueOf(entry))) {
            if (questStr.replace(" ", "").length() < 20){
                String a = "";
                List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(questStr.split(" "));
                for (int j = list1.size()-1 ; j >= 0; j--){
                    a += list1.get(j) + " ";

                }
                lis.add(a);
            }
        }
        return lis;

    }

}
```

Comment: Вопрос должен быть в вопросе, а не где-то по ссылке.

Comment: @Qwertiy просто я маюсь несколько дней а сегодня в 2 ночи дедлайн

Comment: Скорее всего ты не учёл, что нужно вывести первый путь, либо где-то сравниваешь числа как строки. Код мне читать лень, поскольку там какая-то жесть. Вероятно, задачу следует решать по-другому. И почему мы должны помогать тебе нечестно сдавать задачи где-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy а я не прошу решать. Я же решил я прошу помочь, объяснить

Comment: Давайте сначала вы потратите время и поможете нам, объясните ваш собственный код. Потом попробуйте посмотреть, а ваш непроходимый пример вообще имеет выход? И только потом мы может быть поговорим про правило правой руки (как выходят из лабиринта) и в каких случаях этот алгоритм даёт осечку -- многосвязанные лабиринты. Пока вижу халявщика, который ничего не делал, а теперь хочет не своё время потрать, а чужое. Такие пароходы не летают.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ты не учёл, что нужно вывести первый путь, либо где-то сравниваешь числа как строки. Код мне читать лень, поскольку там какая-то жесть.

Вероятно, задачу следует решать по-другому. Используй обычный bfs для поиска кратчайшего пути, но отсортируй массив направлений таким образом, чтобы лексикографически меньшие пути шли раньше.